# How to model a social or dating app using DynameDB? Is that DB appropriate?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-aurora

Imagine I have a Users table and every user can like another user, dislike him/her, block him/her (and be blocked by).
I can model that with several tables, but what I don’t how to send queries like this one (Note that a user could potentially like/dislike/block thousands of users):

Get users in this area (using longitude and attitude this is easy), that I never said I dislike them and I never blocked them.

Something so easy, I am not sure about how to do it.

Should I use Aurora and SQL queries? In that case, I know how to do it.
In my case I don’t mind using Aurora because I will not have millions of records, maybe it is better in my case.

Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the use cases of [Amazon Neptune](https://aws.amazon.com/neptune/)

> Social Networking
>
> Amazon Neptune can quickly and easily process large sets of user
>   profiles and interactions to build social networking applications.
>   Neptune enables highly interactive graph queries with high throughput
>   to bring social features into your applications. For example, if you
>   are building a social feed into your application, you can use Neptune
>   to provide results that prioritize showing your users the latest
>   updates from their family, from friends whose updates they ‘Like,’ and
>   from friends who live close to them.

Comment: I didn't know that service. I will take a look. Thanks.
Anyway, I need something to integrate with AppSync/GraphQL, and right now there are 2 databases, DynamoDB and Aurora.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

PK: "node" string  userid
SK: "edge"[image] sting   userid   (id of the user to express relationship, same id if self)

Attributes : relationship  such as like/dislike/block 
plus all other data u want.

Then create global index  on PK relationship, SK node  or edge  and you can query

Query  like this  "query relationship-index where PK="like" and SK="user"

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, although I don't understand it perfectly. Are you using DynamoDB? Thanks.